# Convert string to double do not respect current number decimal separator

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to convert a string representing a double from invariant culture to a double in current culture representation, I'm concerned with how to get the new double representation to use the current number decimal separator of Current Culture.

I used the code below for the conversion :

```
public static double ConvertToDouble(this object inputVal, bool useCurrentCulture = false)
{
    string currentSep = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    string invariantSep = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    if (inputVal.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        if (!currentSep.Equals(invariantSep))
        {
            inputVal = (inputVal as string).Replace(invariantSep, currentSep);
        }
    }
    if (useCurrentCulture)
        return Convert.ToDouble(inputVal, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    else
        return Convert.ToDouble(inputVal);
}
```

But the above code always gives me a double with ".", although I use the CurrentCulture for example French supposed to give me a double with comma (",").

Many thanks in advance for any hint.

***FreeDev***

Comment: If you're converting a string to double, why does the extension accept an object at all? Also, extensions for `object` are a bad idea in my opinion. You pollute intellisense with a method that you 'll almost never use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and your question i guess that you actually want to convert a `string` to a `double` with either `InvariantCulture` or current-culture. This double should then be converted to a string which is formatted by the current-culture datetime-format informations(like `NumberDecimalSeparator`).

So this method should do two things:

1. parse string to double
2. convert double to string

---

```
public static string ConvertToFormattedDouble(this string inputVal, IFormatProvider sourceFormatProvider = null, IFormatProvider targetFormatProvider = null)
{
    if (sourceFormatProvider == null) sourceFormatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    if (targetFormatProvider == null) targetFormatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    if (sourceFormatProvider == targetFormatProvider)
        return inputVal; // or exception?

    double d;
    bool isConvertable = double.TryParse(inputVal, NumberStyles.Any, sourceFormatProvider, out d);
    if (isConvertable)
        return d.ToString(targetFormatProvider);
    else
        return null; // or whatever
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
string input = "1234.567";
string output = input.ConvertToFormattedDouble();  // "1234,567"
```

Note that i've extended string instead of object. Extensions for object are a bad idea in my opinion. You pollute intellisense with a method that you 'll almost never use (although it applies also to `string`).

---

**Update**:

If you really want to go down this road and use an extension for `object` that supports any kind of numbers as (boxed) objects or strings you could try this extension:

```
public static string ConvertToFormattedDouble(this object inputVal, IFormatProvider sourceFormatProvider = null, IFormatProvider targetFormatProvider = null)
{
    if (sourceFormatProvider == null) sourceFormatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    if (targetFormatProvider == null) targetFormatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

    if (inputVal is string)
    {
        double d;
        bool isConvertable = double.TryParse((string)inputVal, NumberStyles.Any, sourceFormatProvider, out d);
        if (isConvertable)
            return d.ToString(targetFormatProvider);
        else
            return null;
    }
    else if (IsNumber(inputVal))
    {
        decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(inputVal, sourceFormatProvider);
        return Decimal.ToDouble(d).ToString(targetFormatProvider);
    }
    else
        return null;
}

public static bool IsNumber(this object value)
{
    return value is sbyte
            || value is byte
            || value is short
            || value is ushort
            || value is int
            || value is uint
            || value is long
            || value is ulong
            || value is float
            || value is double
            || value is decimal;
}
```

Usage:

```
object input = 1234.56745765677656578d;
string output = input.ConvertToFormattedDouble();  // "1234,56745765678"
```

Comment: I've used an object to extend, for the reason that I'll use this method for decimal, string..
I need the result to be formatted but the type is double 1234,567

Comment: Your solution guided me very well, and after I used the updated one and verfied some results the last day, it's the answer (y). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> But the above code always gives me a double with "." as the NumberDecimalSeparator

No, it returns a `double`. A `double` is *just* a number. It doesn't have a `NumberDecimalSeparator`... only a culture does, and that's only applied when converting to or from strings. Talking about the separator for a `double` is like talking about whether an `int` is in decimal or hex - there's no such concept. 0x10 and 16 are the same value, represented by the same bits.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but it's crucial to understand the difference between what's present in a textual representation, and what's inherent to the data value itself. You should care about the separator when parsing or formatting - but after you've parsed to a `double`, that information is gone.

Comment: Thanks Jhon for the remarks, but its just an example to show that why convertion in current culture having its NumberDecimalSeparator ="," gives a double with ".", have you any ideas ?

Comment: @FreeDev: You seem to have missed my point. There's no such thing as "a double with "."". There's just a `double`. The dot only shows  up when you convert it to text - and that's where you should make the decision about which format to use.

Comment: A method `ConvertToDoubleInvariant` would be a contradiction in terms even without `useCurrentCulture` as parameter. A `double` has no culture as Jon has tried to point out.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I interpreted the "Invariant" part as "using the invariant culture to perform the conversion" which would have made sense. I see the method name in the question has now been changed...